# Spring MVC with Hibernate Validator doesn't show errors from messages.properties

Tags: hibernate, validation, spring-mvc, properties

I have got problem with showing errors messages. I use Spring MVC and sending form like object UserForm and I want to use Hibernate validator, that's work but I cannot see any errors messages.

This is form home.jsp

```
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page session="false" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>

<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="./resources/styles/style.css" media="screen" />
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>
    User Form 
</h1>

<form:form action="addUser" commandName="userform" method="get">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Name: </td>
            <td><form:input path="name"/></td>
            <td><form:errors path="name" cssClass="error"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Text: </td>
            <td><form:textarea path="text"/></td>
            <td><form:errors path="text" cssClass="error"/></td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
            </td>
         </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

There is my controller UserController that handle form above

```
 package cz.solution.controllers;

   import java.util.Date;
import javax.validation.Valid;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import cz.morosystems.form.UserForm;
import cz.morosystems.tools.JobSheduler;


@Controller
public class UserController {


    @RequestMapping(value="/", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showMyform(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("userform", new UserForm());
        return "home";
    }  

    @RequestMapping(value = "/addUser")
    public String showFilledForm(@Valid @ModelAttribute("usermessage") UserForm userform, BindingResult result,
                        Model model) {
        userform.setDate(new Date());
        model.addAttribute("userform", userform);
        if(result.hasErrors()){           
            return "/home";
        }else{
            return "displayUser";
        }

    } 
}
```

UserForm for handling form from home.jsp

```
package cz.solution.form; 

import java.util.Date;    
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;    

public class UserForm {
    @NotEmpty
    private String name;
    @NotEmpty
    private String text;
    private Date date;


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }


    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }


    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }


}
```

I added this to servlet-context.xml

```
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource" id="messageSource">
        <beans:property name="basename" value="messages" />
    </beans:bean>
```

I have messages.properties in folder src/main/resources

```
NotEmpty.userForm.name = Name is required!
NotEmpty.userForm.text = Text is required!
```

When the one of inputs are empty, that's show form again but there is no error message. I tried add to UserForm

```
@NotEmpty(message="Name is required")
    private String name;
```

but no success again. Thanks for all tips.

Answer (score 1):

Solved! In method showFilledForm give @Valid behind @ModelAttribute